Как в сплывающем меню нажать кнопку "OK" в Selenuim

Я пытаюсь через Selenium Java нажать на кнопку "OK" в сплывающем окне, но никак не получается этого сделать.
Вот что я пробовал сделать:
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

Я новичок в Selenium, не могли бы вы мне помочь решить проблему?
